# Finite-order self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-actions, automorphism-groups

Consider the $n$-dimensional euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^n$. A self-homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^n$ is said to be *of finite order* if $\phi^m = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{R}^n}$ for some positive integer $m$.

**Question**: Does every finite order self-homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^n$ have a fixed point?

What I know about it:

If for every divisor $d | m$, the fixed-point set $\left(\mathbf{R}^n\right)^{\phi^d}$ of $\phi^d$ has its cohomology groups $H^*_c\left(\left(\mathbf{R}^n\right)^{\phi^d}, \mathbf{Z}\right)$ finitely generated over $\mathbf{Z}$, then the theorem of "Verdier, *Caractéristique d'Euler-Poincaré*, 1973" will be applicable. In particular, all the self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}^n$ of prime order has a fixed-point.

In that article Verdier derived a formula of the finite group representation on the alternating sum of the cohomology group with $\mathbf{Q}$-coefficients. This in particular implies a version of Lefschetz trace formula for finite-order self-homeomorphisms.

Unfortunately, I don't know if there can be some self-homeomorphism of non-prime order such that a certain power of it has its fixed-point set very complicated.

Comment: So 'automorphism' here doesn't mean anything about algebraic structure?  That is, it's purely a topological question?

Comment: I mean topologically, yes. Maybe my vocabularies are too algebraic.

Comment: I updated the term. By the way, if it was real analytic, woudn't the fixed point set be of finite topological type?

Comment: [Correcting here previous comment] Here's some info from the review of [HKMS] *Haynes, Kwasik, Mast, Schultz, Periodic maps on R7 without
fixed points; Math Proc Camb Phil Soc, 132, p. 131-136, 2002.* by Elmonds. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1866329 (continued)

Comment: Consider $f$ on $R^n$ with $f^m=id$. (1) "classical results of Smith": if $f$ is smooth, and if ($n\le 6$ or $m$ is prime-power) then answer is yes. (2) Kister, 1961-63 relying on Conner-Floyd 1959: construction of fixed-point-free smooth periodic maps on $R^8$. (3) [HKMS] for any $m$ non-prime-power and $n\ge 7$, existence of such smooth $f$. (4) Oliver 1979 fixed-point-free self-homeo on $R^n$ for $n\ge 6$ when $m$ is divisible by at least 3 primes. (5) (no ref): answer is yes for $n\le 4$ without smoothness. Open when $n=5$.

Comment: I can't find any discussion about the case when $f$ is assumed real analytic, or polynomial.

Comment: In the polynomial case, the fixed point set of any power of $f$ is always homotopically equivalent to a finite CW-complex. So by Verdier's trace formula, $f$ always has a fixed point.

Comment: @WilleLiou I'm not sure I get the argument in the polynomial case. Say, $f^6=id$. The fixed-point set of both $f^2$ and $f^3$ are non-empty, but I don't see why they are, say, connected. But I'm still far from a correct understanding of Verdier's formula.

Comment: @YCor With Verdier's formula, if we take the trace of $f$, the left hand side will give $\pm 1$, since the only compactly supported cohomology of $X=\mathbf{R}^n$ is $H^{n}_c(X, \mathbf{Q}) \cong \mathbf{Q}$. On the right hand side, only the subset $X_G$ will contribute, so the Euler characteristic of the fixed point set must be $\pm 1$, depending on whether $f$ preserves or inverses the orientation. However, it doesn't say anything about the connectedness for any power of $f$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is, naturally, a huge history regarding a basic question like this.  This particular problem was figured out between 1930 and the early 1960's.  The main names are P.A. Smith, Conner, Floyd. Here is a math review to get you going:

[MR0130929](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0130929) (24 #A783) Reviewed
Kister, J. M.
[Examples of periodic maps on Euclidean spaces without fixed points](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1961-10641-1).
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 67 1961 471–474.
54.80 (57.47)

Let T be a homeomorphism of period r on Euclidean space En. The classical result of P. A. Smith is that T has a fixed point if r is prime [Ann. of Math. (2) 35 (1934), 572–578] or a prime power [Amer. J. Math. 63 (1941), 1–8; [MR0003199](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0003199)]. The author settles a question of long standing with the following theorem: If r is not a prime power, then there exists a triangulation μ of $E^{9r}$ and a homeomorphism T of period r on $E^{9r}$ without a fixed point, such that T is simplicial over μ. The construction is a modification of an example due to Conner and Floyd [Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 10 (1959), 354–360; [MR0105115](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0105115)].

Comment: The words "naturally", "basic" and "Do some reading!" suggest that the OP ought to know better, which is unfortunate -- if he were expert here, he wouldn't be asking. The question strikes me as being MO-appropriate.